# The Dreaded Malformed Response for Lambda Proxy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-api

I'm working on an integration with the Google Calendar API from an AWS Lambda function. The code works fine on my desktop as a Node.js app, but when I push the code to Lambda, I get a 502 Server error with the Malformed Response message in the log. I've set up a layer with googleapi Node module (I've confirmed the versions all match) and that doesn't seem to be the issue. I'm sort of new to Lambda, so I'm stumped as to what I may have done wrong.

Code below:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const apiKey = process.env.APIKEY
const calendarId = process.env.CALENDAR_ID
const cal = google.calendar({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: apiKey
});


//--------------- Utility Functions --------------------
function lastDayInMonth(month, year) {
  const daysInMonth = [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31,30, 31 ];
  return ((month == 1) && 
          (((year % 4 == 0) && (year %100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))) 
          ? daysInMonth[month] + 1 
          : daysInMonth[month]
}

//------------------- handler -------------------------------
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    
    var headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Content-Type, X-Amz-Date, Authorization, X.Api-Key, X-Amz-Security-Token',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    };
    
    // Get the month, year from the search parameters
    let month, year = -1
    if (event.queryStringParameters) {
        if (event.queryStringParameters.month) {
            month = event.queryStringParameters.month;
        }
        if (event.queryStringParameters.year) {
            year = event.queryStringParameters.year;
        }
    }
    
    let response = {
        "statusCode": 500,
        "multiValueHeaders": headers,
        "body": '',
        "isBase64Encoded": false
    }
    
    // test for bad dates
    if (month == -1 || year == -1) {
        response.body = JSON.stringify('Bad dates')
        return(response)
    } else {
        // set up the call to the Google Calendar API
        const startDate = new Date(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0).toISOString();
        const endDate = new Date(year, month, lastDayInMonth(month, year),23,59,59).toISOString();
        const userTimeZone = 'America/Los_Angeles'
        let res_parms = {
            "timeMin": startDate,
            "timeMax": endDate,
            "timeZone": userTimeZone,
            "calendarId": calendarId,
        }
        // retrieve the list of events
        cal.events.list(res_parms )
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('Call was successful')
            response.statusCode = 200
            response.body = JSON.stringify(result)
            console.log(response)
            callback(null, {"statusCode": 200, "body": JSON.stringify(result)})
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log('call failed')
            response.statusCode = 500
            response.body = 'No date retrieved'
            callback(null, response);
        })
    }
};
```

Any ideas, etc., are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this code work if you test it in lambda? What does it return with some test event object?

Comment: @Marcin I've been testing the function with the API GW. I'm not really clear on how to test an HTTP GET method in Lambda.

Comment: @404 Thanks for the catch. Cut and paste inheritance at the end of the day. Fixed it.

Comment: I should clarify that by fixed it, I meant to say that I removed the unneeded JSON.stringify. The error persists...

Answer (score 0):

Use a POST method, not a GET method and this code:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const apiKey = process.env.APIKEY
const calendarId = process.env.CALENDAR_ID
const cal = google.calendar({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: apiKey
})

//--------------- Utility Functions --------------------
function lastDayInMonth(month, year) {
  const daysInMonth = [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31,30, 31 ];
  return ((month == 1) && 
          (((year % 4 == 0) && (year %100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))) 
          ? daysInMonth[month] + 1 // account for leap year
          : daysInMonth[month]
}

//--------- Handler to call Google Calendar API ---------
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    // retrieve the month and year
    const { month, year } = JSON.parse(event.body)
    
    // set up the headers for the response
    var headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Content-Type, X-Amz-Date, Authorization, X.Api-Key, X-Amz-Security-Token',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
    
    // set up the base response fields
    const response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": headers,
        "body": ''
    }
    
    // set the start date for the beginning of the of the first day of the month
    const startDate = new Date(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0).toISOString()

    // set the start date for the end of the of the last day of the month
    const endDate = new Date(year, month, lastDayInMonth(month, year), 23, 59, 59).toISOString()
    
    // set the time zone
    const timeZone = 'Americad/Los_Angeles'
    
    // set up the parameters for the call to the Google Calendar API
    const res_params = {
        'timeMin': startDate,
        'timeMax': endDate,
        'timeZone': timeZone,
        'calendarId': calendarId,
        'singleEvents': true,
        'orderBy': 'startTime'
    }
    
    await cal.events.list(res_params)
    .then(result => {
        response.body = JSON.stringify(result)
    })
    .catch(e => {
        response.body = 'Error in retrieving events'
    })

    return response
}
```